# Page numbering and sections

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, page-numbers

Consider this image:
[image]

As you can see I am having difficulties with the page numbering. The left page is **15** (section 2) as it should, but the right one is **2** (section 4). What I think that happened:

By inserting a multi-column lay-out at the bottom of the left page, that page is divided into three sections. At the top section 2, then the multi-column (section 3) and at the bottom the section after the columns (section 4).

Because section 2 is force-started at 1 (as it should) and new sections by default link to the previous one, section 3 (the multi-column) 'thinks' it has a page number as well. Because it is linked to the previous section (2) it starts again at page number 1. Then, of course, section 4 follows which I can edit freely. The problem is that I cannot seem to edit the "invisible footer" of section 3 so that it is NOT linked to section 2 anymore and that I can allow it to let it continue its numbering from the previous section.

How can I do this? I've been struggling with this for days but can't get it to work.

I hope that my explanation is clear.

Comment: @Scott: Just in case you didn't know, all images uploaded to imgur and embedded in questions/answers on SE *are* full-size. They haven't been permanently resized/shrunk, and you can always open an image by itself to view it at its original size. For example, in Firefox right-click the image above and select "View Image".

Comment: @Karan: Yes, I know that.  But I’m stuck with IE, which *doesn’t* have “View Image”.  Yes, I know that I can get “Properties”, copy the URL, open a new tab, and paste the URL –– it’s just nice not to have to jump through that many hoops.

Comment: @Scott: The fastest way in most browsers including IE is to drag the image and drop it onto the address bar. That's the same as "View Image" and you can use Alt+Left/Right arrow to quickly flip between post and image if required.

Comment: @Karan: I’ve got IE9, and that doesn’t work for me.

Comment: @Scott: It doesn't? Hmm, not sure if that was the case back when I had IE9. Perhaps there's an add-on that can replicate "View Image" for IE. Let's see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click in Section 3 (the multi-column block) and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, to force a page break.  This will give you a page (“16”) that exposes the Section 3 header and footer.  Configure them as needed, then go back and delete the page break.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks, it works now! I can't believe there is an easier solution for this though. What if you are working with multiple lay-outs on a single page. You then have the repeat this process a numerous times. Well, it's better than nothing I suppose. thanks again!

Comment: I’m curious how you got into your problem in the first place.  When I insert a section break, the new section is initially formatted to continue page numbering from the previous section.

Comment: It's because section 2 has been set to start numbering at 1 explicitly. This means that the next section (i.e. the multi-column) will automatically take over the previous footer settings and thus it will also force-start with page number 1. Or at least that's the most logical explanation I can come up with.